# issue with access database in visual studio. program works in windows 7 but not on windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I am currently writing a c# program in visual studio, in which I need to use an access database.  In windows 7, the program works flawlessly, but in windows 10 the following line throws an exception.
 `private const string databasePath = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=School_Project.accdb";`

Comment: what is the exception. . Please add more detail to reproduce the issue. Please read how to ask

Comment: System.invalidOperationException

Comment: it says that the provider is not knowned in the system

Answer (score 0):

> UWP app deal only with SQLite.

If you want use oledb in your project you need to add reference oledb in the project. That's not supported on UWP windows 10 application.

[sqlite migration](https://www.bing.com/search?q=mdb%20to%20sqlite)

I propose you two tracks to explore:

- Convert your .mdb file into sqlite "Ready to use".
- Develop Web API that exposes the data of your mdb.